# Google Maps Api get lat long dynamically

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to do something like aerophotography simulator as my university project, using Google Maps Api. For this, I need dynamically change viewport of a map, but for this I have to get lat and long of center of my viewport. Is there any way to do that, using Google Maps Api standart functions?

Comment: you want to get the coordinates (LatLng) associated with the center point (x,y) of the MapView?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I need to get them, and after that - change them a bit to move my viewport.

Comment: Just use `LatLng latLng = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;` (assuming your `MapView` is `mMap`)

Comment: I've just tried this and it works just fine, thank you! Can I also ask you, what is the best way to move my map viewport along, for example, X axis, with some kind of speed, that I can choose?

Comment: In order to animate the camera position use this `mMap.animateCamera(location);` where `location` is the next location you wish to show on the map (LatLng object)

Comment: That's everything I need! Thank you, and excuse me for stupid questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the coordinates (LatLng) associated with the center point (x,y) of the MapView you can use the method `getCameraPosition()`.

(Assuming your `GoogleMap` object is mMap)

`LatLng latLng = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;`

In order to animate the camera position use the method `animateCamera()`, something like this:

`mMap.animateCamera(location);`

where location is the next location you wish to show on the map (`LatLng` object).